# IAP over HTTP STM32

Tags: ethernet

I am using a STM32F207 Controller interfaced to a Micrel KSZ8995FQ in MII Mode. I use IAP over HTTP available from the ST website for the STM32 Controller.

I am able to upgrade the firmware using HTTP, but if my application (image uploaded using the IAP Code) as well as the IAP Code have the same IP Address, I get a response to the ping command from the application code only after approximately 5 minutes.

I am sure that the application starts running. This situation (delayed response for the ping the from application) is not seen when I use a different IP address in the IAP Code and bootloader code.

Comment: You're referring to sites, can we have links? Also, please list the relevant code.

Comment: I would add `stm32` tag to this... may be also say what IAP means and link to the app note would be useful for the readers.

Comment: Des the same thing happen when pinged from a different computer to the one you programmed with?

Comment: Yes,the same thing happens when pinged from a different computer to the one used for programming

Comment: This is actually a universal IP/ethernet problem, device details don't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the arp cache on the pc you are using, or ensure that the MAC address of the stm32 does not change during or as a result of the upgrade.

If it does change, you will either need administrator/root access to delete the old arp record for it, or to wait for that record to expire, so that the pc issues a new arp request to find its current MAC address.

Comment: OP said pinging from another computer had same problem, or perhaps I didn't phrase question correctly :P.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone. The MAC Address configured by the Bootloader is reconfigured by the application causing the issue. Confirmed by deleting the arp cache as suggested by Mr. Chris startton, as well as by having same MAC ID in application and bootloader.